# Return an Ajax Response from EventSubscriber?

Tags: 8, ajax, event-subscribers

I am trying to return an ajax response when a user logs in while the page is loading post-login.

/#1 approach was attaching an ajax callback to the user login form submit with form_alter. However this callback fires right on submit and I need an ajax callback to fire after the front page loads post-login.

/#2 approach, I made a user login event and subscriber instantiated during hook_user_login. This works perfectly, I can do a drupal_set_message after a user logs in. **But how would I return an ajax response from the event subscriber?**

eventsubscriber peared down

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      UserLoginEvent::EVENT_NAME => 'onUserLogin',
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Subscribe to the user login event dispatched.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\gary_custom\Event\UserLoginEvent $event
   *   Dat event object yo.
   */
  public function onUserLogin(UserLoginEvent $event) {
    //$response = new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse();
    //$response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AlertCommand('test'));
    //return $response; does not work
    drupal_set_message(t('Testy testy')); //works
  }
```

Comment: An Ajax response is requested by js code in the browser targeting a route and controller in Drupal. Why would you want to return it from an event subscriber?

Comment: There's not really such a concept as an AJAX response, just an AJAX _request_ - and that's made by JavaScript. So if you need to invoke an AJAX request from the post-login page, you need to inject some JavaScript into that page to make that request.

Comment: thanks, I guess that was my misunderstanding then. Any clues on how I would inject an ajax request only once after the user logs in? I wonder if theres a way I could inject an empty container with hook_user_login and just listen for that and then perform an ajax request

Comment: If you're happy with quick and dirty...make a service with two methods: `setLoggingIn` and `getLoggingIn`, which set and get a variable (whose default value is `FALSE`) in the class respectively. In the event subscriber, call `$your_service->setLoggingIn(TRUE);`, and in an implementation of `hook_page_attachments_alter()`, call `if ($your_service->getLoggingIn()) {`. If the condition passes, add a library which references a JS file that performs the AJAX request to the attachments array

Comment: Actually that might not work (I think the response to the login POST is a redirect to the user page, at which point the attachments would be lost). An alternative would be to store the logging in state in the session and pick it up from there instead

Comment: You might be approaching what you're trying to accomplish the wrong way. What's the reason behind this? mind sharing what exactly you're trying to do in non-code speak?

Comment: I have similar need, I would like to change drupalSettings or find some other way to communicate with JS app that is embed in drupal site. But seems that method that is used on EventSubscriber can't do that. Will try to find some other, right approach.